# Why does myArray not get initialized?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"ARRAY INITIALIZED"); //THIS NEVER OCCURS
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: And what if you put the NSLog at the beginning of the function?

Comment: The function just does not get called. I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just putting your initialization code in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`. You would need to make sure you don't `alloc` multiple times (and orphan memory in the process), but it would get called regardless of whether this is rigged up in the `xib` or programmatically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if(!myArray)
    {
         myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you creating your table programmatically or is it in Interface Builder?  If it's in interface builder, then you need to override `-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` instead.

Comment: I am just subclassing. 
@interface InboxTableViewController : UITableViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
 
 NSMutableArray *myArray;


}

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell from your given code, but if you're making your controller programmatically, make sure you're initializing your subclass:

```
[[MyCustomTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:style];
```

Rather than `UITableViewController`:

```
[[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:style];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that initWithStyle never gets called. I forgot to mention, the initial window is build in IB, so my custom controllers are called from the xib, and i have to override initWithCoder....

http://www.iosdeveloperforums.com/thread-initwithstyle-overriding

Comment: if that's the case then initWithCoder is getting called and you need to move your init code in there.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what my answer is stating.